# How to import a python file from another directory in current working python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, export, streamlit

I am trying to import a python file from another directory in my current working python file as shown below snapshot. I would appreciate if you guys can share how to achieve it.

[image]

In `dashboard.py` I tried :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/lungsang/Desktop/streamlit-practice/level-packs')
import usage.py
```

`usage.py` is in `level-packs` directory.

as of now its not working..

Comment: never use dashes for directorys, use underscore instead.

Comment: Try to import just the file name `import usage`

Comment: Can you copy and paste the absolute path of **level-packs** here? Just right click on the folder and copy **absolute path**

Comment: /home/lungsang/Desktop/streamlit-practice/level_pack

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/lungsang/Desktop/streamlit-practice/level-packs')
import usage.py
```

by

```
import sys
sys.path.append("levelpacks") # or sys.path.append("/home/lungsang/Desktop/streamlit-practice/levelpacks")
import levelpacks.usage as usage
```

the "-" seems to be an issue, you need to change your folder name

**About your last edit:**

The usage.py file **is not directly** in your levelpacks folder

So you need to do

```
import sys
sys.path.append("levelpacks") # or sys.path.append("/home/lungsang/Desktop/streamlit-practice/levelpacks")
import levelpacks.level_packs.usage as usage
```

Comment: There is no way your second code will work.

Comment: I have updated my question, error says ```no module named 'usage'```

Comment: Import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()) and then import level-packs.usage

Comment: @ YfNk, I have update the question, plz have a look :)

Comment: @lungsang check this, it worked for me : import sys
    sys.path.append("levelpacks")
    import levelpacks.usage   (you need to rename your "level-packs" folder to "levelpacks"

Comment: i'll update my answer up here

Comment: @YfNk I tried like you. But still not working !

Comment: still error  no module named 'usage' ?

Comment: error says : Unused import statement 'import levelpacks.usage'

Comment: So it works, this is informing you that you imported it but you don't use it somewhere else

Comment: If you are using usage module somewhere else, use it as level packs.usage or replace import level packs.usage by import level packs.usage as usage

Comment: I didn't get the whole idea of what you mean :) Usauly usage.py is for starting a pipeline and I want to import it in dashboard.

Comment: I have update the question, can you plz check :)

Comment: let me correct my answer according to your last edit

Answer (score 0):

```
def levelpack_ui():
    from levelpacks.level_packs import create_packs
    create_packs()
```

After applying above method, it's working fine. thank you :)